# How to create objects from JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller which is used to parse a site.  From that parsing, I get a JSON object.  In that JSON object I have mainly two things: prices and images.

So, a Page has many Price and Image.  First thing I do when creating the controller is:

```
@page = Page.create(:url => parsed_url)
```

Then from the @output, I want to be able to create several @images and @prices.  So, I do this:

```
@prices = @output["prices"]
@images = @output["images"]
```

So, `@images` look like `[{:width => 12, :height => 13, :src => 'http...'}, {:width => 20,..}]`

I want to create an Image associated with that `@page` for each object in the array. Before doing that though I might need to check those attributes (width, height) and manipulate them before inserting them to the DB. So my question is... Where and how should I do this?

I know how to create an Image by doing `Image.create(:page_id => @page.id, :width => 12...)`, but how do I do that form that JSON response that needs to be treated first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Image.create`, use `Image.new` or `@page.images.build`:

```
@output["images"].each do |image_data|
  image = @page.images.build image_data
  //...  manipulate as needed
  image.save
end
```

Comment: What about using before_create to manipulate the data? For manipulation I basically need to do some calculations among some attributes to fill the value of another attribute.

Comment: @HommerSmith: You could do that, although model callbacks are typically intended to be used to ensure data integrity.  If this is a business concern, it may be more wise to separate it out to a component that handles this, allowing you to swap it out if needed.  That said, a callback will certainly work just fine.